# How to use DataGridViewLinkColumn for display a Link in one columns

Tags: c#, winforms

I try to put data into DataGridView and have one column for display a "link" but it  create columns from amount of "link data"

```
ArrayList row = new ArrayList();
foreach (S3Object entry in response.S3Objects)
{
    row = new ArrayList();
    row.Add(Path.GetFileName(entry.Key.ToString()));
    row.Add((double)entry.Size / 1024 / 1024 + " MB");
    row.Add(entry.LastModified);
    row.Add(entry.Owner.DisplayName);
    DTGfilenames.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());

    DataGridViewLinkColumn dgvLink = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
    dgvLink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
    dgvLink.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;
    dgvLink.HeaderText = "Preview";
    dgvLink.Name = "URLHERE";
    dgvLink.LinkColor = Color.Blue;
    dgvLink.TrackVisitedState = true;
    dgvLink.Text = "URLHERE";
    dgvLink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
    Console.WriteLine(dgvLink.Name + "  " + dgvLink.Text);
    DTGfilenames.Columns.Add(dgvLink);
}
```

[image: Current result]

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing a `row.Add(dgvLink);` and then call `DTGfilenames.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());` at the end? And get rid of the ` DTGfilenames.Columns.Add(dgvLink);` ...

Comment: @rene  Can you advise me more?,  i'm quite do not understand

Answer (score 0):

Its creates new column because of `DTGfilenames.Columns.Add(dgvLink);` inside the foreach loop.

If there is 10 items in array it will loop 10x and create column link 10x.

But you can try to remove   `DataGridViewLinkColumn dgvLink = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();` inside the loop and paste it before the loop